# AWS InterruptedException: sleep interrupted com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, configuration

we have a web application use AWS (Amazone api), in the coreConfiguration class we create a awsApi bean with predestroy method, the code for coreConfiguration is:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
    public IGridStorageManager awsApi() {
.....
}
```

in awsApi class we have detroy methode, the code is:

```
@Override
    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        if (clientS3 != null) {
            clientS3.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

My problem is sometime in PROD when i use the API i see thos logs:

```
2020-08-03 11:27:00.090 DEBUG 25172 --- [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper : Reaper thread:
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper.run(IdleConnectionReaper.java:188)
```

I read that this exception can cause memory leak, i found that we need to use a shutdown() method, the problem is i aleardy use `@PreDestroy` method with shutdown method, why i have those exceptions ?

Can you help me ?

Thanks